# Keep DropDown Caret animation on items hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-animations

I have a BS4 dropdown element and I am animating the little caret on the right side of the toggle. This works wonderful so far, but only as long as the mouse is hovering the dropdown item. When I hover over the submenu items the caret rotates back. This should not happen until the mouse leaves dropdown AND dropdown-menu.

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 7px;
}
  .dropdown.show {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }

 .dropdown a::before {
   content: "";
 }

 .dropdown a.dropdown-toggle {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 3px 7px;
}

.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle::after {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  content: ">";
  color: Orange;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle:hover::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
    
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: initial;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 7px;
  font-size: initial;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scale(1,0);
  display: block;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}
a.dropdown-item {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2.9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.dropdown-item:hover {
  color: Orange;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    MAIN
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub1</a><br/>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub2</a><br/>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As the animated rotate in this included snippet does not work for unknown reason I have prepared a Codepen as well. Here you can see the rotation:
https://codepen.io/SchweizerSchoggi/pen/GRoZYqV

My wish is to keep the rotated caret as long as the mouse position is over dropdown or the dropdown-menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since with css you can't go back to "previous siblings" (let alone parent) elements, you can position the dropdown-toggle element after the menu like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub3</a>
  </div>

  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MAIN</a>
</div>
```

so that on hover of the menu the dropdown-toggle element can be reached like this:

```
.dropdown-menu:hover + a:after{
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Here is [the working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7hzq5mef/)

Comment: Perfect, works exactly as what I was looking for! Thank you for spending your time on this and have a nice weekend!

Comment: I am glad it solved your problem. Have a nice weekend as well! :)